# Generic Set of Suppliers of Sets

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a Set of Suppliers of Sets. The inner set can be of any type (String, Number, etc...). I want to be able to both add Suppliers to this Set, and retrieve them. When I retrieve them, I understand that I won't know what type of Set the Supplier is returning, and am ok with it being a `Supplier<Set<Object>>`. How do I declare this Set?

I tried

1.

```
Set<Supplier<Set>>
```

Which works, but then I'm not generic-izing the inner Set, which seems wrong

2.

```
Set<Supplier<Set<Object>>>
```

But then I can't add a `Supplier<Set<String>>`

3.

```
Set<Supplier<Set<?>>>
```

But I still can't add the above (and won't be able to take anything out of that set, I imagine)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried making the creation method generic? `<T> Set<Supplier<Set<T>>> createSupplierSets()`

Comment: @daniu I don't have a method like that because I have to add a few sets from different places. So it will have to be using .add()

Comment: The only issue with this is the compile-time warnings.  Generics use the technique "Erasure" which means all the generics <type> are removed and replaced by a suitable generic type - usually `Object`.  The generics have no runtime representation.  Can you accept the warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare as `Set<Supplier<? extends Set<?>>>`.
I think the reason why it works is because `Supplier<?>` is the supertype of any Supplier, and `Supplier<? extends Set<?>>` is the supertype of any Set Supplier. While`Supplier<Set<?>>` is not the same type as any concrete typed Set Supplier for example `Supplier<Set<String>>`.

Comment: Very interesting. Mind going into a little more detail about how exactly this works?

Comment: @Sherz Which is more interesting is that I have no idea...Tried it and it complied. I'm waiting a real answer as well. Guess I'm just an engineer :)

Comment: A question mark is a signifier for 'any type'. So, in this case Any type extending or implementing Set<Any Type>.

Comment: A demo using this approach. https://www.jdoodle.com/a/gAV. (If I understand it well enough.)

Comment: @MichaelMcKay `Supplier`'s `get()` method returns directly a `Set`, there is no need to check the type and cast.

Comment: @grape_mao - Thanks. Updated the doodle.